# Blender Animation channels duplicate

Tags: animation

Blender refuses to add a key pose for the selected bone due to the fact that it adds a key to a wrong channel. I can see it in the curves editor. As you can see i have two similar channels for the same bone wich confuses blender into adding a key into one set of channels but not the other thus the changes in the position or rotations are not visible in the viewport. Why does it happen and is there a way to remove similar channels?
[image]
Ive checked it thorugh python call too
[image]

Comment: Please consider sharing your .blend file with us, you can do so by uploading it to [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to add the provided text into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happened. It could have been done by python through an add-on operator. Anyway, you can remove the problematic channels by clicking on their names on the left and pressing <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>.